Snowflake - Make changes from Excel
I have a table in excel with two columns id and reference and the corresponding db table in Snowflake with the same two columns (and many more). I need to update the reference value from excel into snowflake matching on id. How can I do this?

What dbms are you using?

You can create a table in Snowflake (using COPY INTO or Web Interface or some other method) with your excel file then update your table with a query like (say your existing table is TableA and the table you create with Excel file is TableB):
UPDATE TableA
JOIN TableB USING (id)
SET TableA.RefCol = TableB.RefCol

